# rage4 API, create a basic domain = null

Tags: php, api, curl

I am using the sample code from  ->  https://gbshouse.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/109834-rage4-dns-developers-api#create_regular_domain  to create a basic domain in the Rage4 system for the very first time via API.
But following the call I get a NULL value returned.
I double checked my username and pass/api key and it is verified good.
I don't get any log errors in the rage4 system though.

code used:

```
<?php
$name = 'testdom4.com';
$email = 'admin@testdom4.com';
$username = 'user@testdom4.com';
$password = '4444444444444444444a1e42a';
    $ch = curl_init("https://secure.rage4.com/RAPI/CreateRegularDomain/?name=" . $name . "&email=" . $email);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
?>
```

Did I miss something in the backend to initialize?
How do I create a basic domain via api in the rage4 system?